# What is the magnetic force acting on a non-charged ferrous object at rest?

Tags: electromagnetism

Say I hold a magnet in one hand and an iron screw in the other hand. What is the force acting on the screw and the magnet? What's the formula for this?
I've seen `F = qvB`, but `q` and `v` are zero if the screw is uncharged and at rest. Is this formula just not the correct one for the situation?

Answer (score 0):

The object may appear to be static, but the ferrous material's electrons are moving.

That puts this in the realm of Lorentz Force Law and with that formula you've got the right idea.  Now let's consider the force as a vector product F=qvB = qvB sin theta.

Comment: How do I calculate q and v, then?